# atom-live-server - resource not found error

Tags: html, http, atom-editor, atom-liveserver

Installed `atom-live-server` using atom IDE

Using atom IDE, launching `atom-live-server` for an html page,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Classes</title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="code.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

where `code.js` is,

```
var Greeter = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Greeter(message) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }
    Greeter.prototype.greet = function () {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    };
    return Greeter;
}());
var greeter = new Greeter("world");
console.log(greeter.greeting);
```

---

gives below error in console,

```
Live reload enabled.

Failed to load resource: `http://127.0.0.1:3000/favicon.ico` the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

---

Why live-reload server searching for resource `favicon.ico`?

Answer (score 0):

Just Install "npm install -g live-server" into cmd . then goto your project like cd your project folder name. then run the command "live-server" into cmd. it will automatically open the browser and make your project live reload. No need to atom-live-server or any editor live-reload. Because sometimes atom-live-server doesn't work properly. I personally use it all of my projects. You can try it.